# D3 force layout graph causes slowness in firefox browser

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a dynamic force graph which runs every 3 mins (using setInterval I am calling update, start in the below order)

- `viz.update(); //attach new data from server like viz.path.data(data.links)`,
- `viz.nodes.data(..)`
- `viz.enter(); // viz.path.enter().append("path")`
- `viz.exit(); // path.exit().remove()`
- `force.start();`

when I leave the browser open for sometime, browser slows down and the nodes move slowly when I drag them. Am I missing some thing here..

Help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle to help you out?

Comment: How many nodes are we talking about? If you're getting new nodes all the time, you're going to run into various performance limits pretty quickly.

Comment: Do you have this same problem with Chrome/Chromium? I found d3.js to run much better there (at the expense of using more memory)

Comment: Node number are close to 100. Plus I will not be getting new nodes all the time. At first instance if its 90, in the next reload, its would range between 90 - 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG performance in Firefox is slower than in Webkit/Chrome and IE10.

Still performance in Firefox is not bad. There are a few things you can try.

- Be sure you are not leaving unused/empty elements around (like <g>s), and have everything properly cleaned up. Too many elements will kill your performance quickly.
- Reduce the amount of nodes that use opacity, try to use it as little as possible.
- Reduce the amount of elements.

One thing I also did, but not sure if it is any help, was to call force.stop() before calling force.start() again.

Comment: I'm working on a complex set of interactive graphs right now with d3 and angular.. and everything except IE<=8 and FF run perfectly. That is a bad group to be in for FF.