# d3 force layout and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I'm using a D3.js and creating a force layout to animate a bunch of circles floating around. It worked great with webkit browsers, but I was disappointed to see it runs REALLY slow and clunky in Firefox.

This was asked here: [D3 force layout graph causes slowness in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181153/d3-force-layout-graph-causes-slowness-in-firefox-browser)

But the "answer" was basically to just not do as much stuff so FF doesn't have to work so hard. I'd rather not water down the effect. So my question is how I can do something equivalent without crushing FF.

For example, can Raphael do this in a way that Firefox can handle better?

Is there another library that's more x-browser friendly?

Maybe another idea?

Comment: Define what you mean by "something similar".  Which parts of the animation are important to you?  Do you have a lot of nodes or only a few, are they simple circles or complex graphics?  Raphael isn't likely to be an improvement, but for some types of very complex visualizations using `<canvas>`-based graphics can ease the browser load because you don't have separate DOM elements for each node.  [Example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3180395)

Comment: I guess I want to maintain the ability to interact with the individual nodes separately. If I use a canvas they'll all become frozen in position whereas svg elements can be animated individually, right?

Comment: Pretty much.  You can animate canvas by re-drawing sections of it, but if you want the user to interact with the nodes then you end up with a lot of code to figure out which node image is under the mouse, and that might cancel out any efficiencies.  And if canvas is out, I'm afraid I don't have any suggestions beyond those on the other question: focus on making the graphics easy to paint and reposition.  Maybe I'd add: If you're not already, try using `transform` to position the nodes instead of `x`/`y`.  It makes a big difference with HTML, haven't really tested with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/).

This is a cross-browser graphic library based on HTML canvas (as opposed to SVG), with the emphasis on high performance and animations. You CAN manipulate graphic primitives with this library, even though they are rendered in canvas.

Unfortunately, and to my knowledge, it does not have built-in solution for a force layout. That said, it does not seem impossible to develop it.

Hope this helps.